# Tinkerpop 3.1 on OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

is there any way to run Tinkerpop Gremlin 3.1 traversals in OrientDB?
I've noticed that currently the DBMS supports the previous version (2.x) of the Tinkerpop traversal language which, for example, only allows to directly filter edges by label, but not vertices :( .

I was quite satisfied with [gremlin-scala](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala) and [orientDB-gremlin](https://github.com/mpollmeier/orientdb-gremlin) but I found that not all my queries where efficiently executed (some indexes were ignored).
Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think there are other options.  orientdb-gremlin is still under development. you will have to bring your issues up with their development crew.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot, @stephenmallette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orientdb-gremlin is indeed the only available driver, and while it works pretty well for base cases there's some work left for index usage. If you report your cases in a github issue we can have a look. Best is obviously if you submit a PR :)