# Does OrientDb makes use of indexes when using Tinkerpop3?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Does OrientDb makes use of indexes when using Tinkerpop3?

The last answer for this question was in 2015. Anythign changed since then? [Tinkerpop 3.1 on OrientDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199876/tinkerpop-3-1-on-orientdb)

I'm currently using Orientdb3.0.9 with orientdb-gremlin library that uses Tinkerpop3

Comment: Which version of OrientDB and Tinkerpop you use?

Comment: I am just starting to use OrientDb. So i chose to use the latest versions :  3.0.9 of orientDb and Tinkerpop3